# Hash Join Algorithm from MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql

Assume I want to write the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT Employee.Name, Employee.ID, InvitedToParty.Name, InvitedToParty.FavoriteFood
FROM Employee, InvitedToParty
WHERE Employee.Name = InvitedToParty.Name
```

given the required tables :

```
Employee

ID  Name     Birthday
1   Heiny    01.01.2000
2   Peter    10.10.1990
3   Sabrina  12.10. 2015
.
.

InvitedToParty

Name    FavoriteFood
Michael Pizza
Heiny   Pizza
Sabrina Burger
George  Pasta
.
.
.
```

Assume I have this information as two lists in Python inside a dictionary:

```
tables['Employee'].id = [1, 2, 3 ..]
tables['Employee'].Name = [Heiny, Peter, Sabrina ...]
```

I hope you get the idea. These keys of the dictionary have attributes, because I created a class for each table.

How can I write this query in Python? My initial idea was (pseudo):

```
match_counter = 0

for i, value in enumerate(table1.column):

    for j in range(len(table2.column)):

        if table2.column[j] == value:

            table2.column[j], table2.column[i] = table2.column[i], table2.column[]
            match_counter += 1
```

And remove everything after `'match_counter'` rows. But I am sure there must be a better way? Moreover, I do not even know if this would give me the correct result

Comment: If this is coming from MySQL, then why not just let MySQL do the work?  It's optimized for exactly this role.

Comment: It is not, it is just for better intuition of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The rough equivalent of your query is:

```
results = []
for row1 in table1:
    for row2 in table2:
        if row1.Name == row2.Name:
            results.append( row1.Name, row1,ID, row2.FavoriteFood )
```